# JMS and JMX tutorials?

Tags: java, jms, jmx

i am preparing for an interview which requires a bit hands on JMS and JMX, but i didnt work on these. so need any video tutorial links which can make me understand quickly. 
thanks.

Comment: how come this question was not downvoted?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't have any video to suggest. However, I can suggest the following tutorials to get started with JMS and JMX.

- For JMS

  - [JMS Tutorial and Code Camps](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/index.html)
  - [Chapter 31 The Java Message Service API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncdq.html) in the Java EE 5 tutorial
- For JMX

  - [Getting Started with Java Management Extensions (JMX): Developing Management and Monitoring Solutions](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jmx.html)
  - [Lesson: Overview of the JMX Technology](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/overview/index.html) in the Java Tutorials
  - [Java Management Extensions (JMX) Technology Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jmx/tutorial/tutorialTOC.html)

PS: Maybe videos work well for you but, to my experience, the most effective way to learn something is hands-on practice - and this especially true with programming - and I warmly recommend to take some hours to practice a bit. The above tutorials can help.